# Map Resources for Map Development

Tags: google-maps, maps, bing-maps

I am attempting a GPS application and i wanted to use Google maps API to create it. I was wondering if you guys had any resources such as the name of some books, websites, videos that i can purchase, and tutorials that i can look at to help me in creating the application. I am looking at using technologies such as java and flash to accomplish this. I also want to include a lot of custom objects on the map such to mimic real world objects such as cars, people and so on.

Also any comments on the use of the API would also be useful since i know there is also BING out there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have a bunch of examples,tutorials,  demoes and documentations on google maps home page http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html You can also check examples in action and try your own modification in google code playground http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/ There is another tutorial here: http://econym.org.uk/gmap/